# How to fix CORS error in facebook login in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm using `passport.js` and its `Facebook strategy` to implement a Facebook login system. But when from frontend which is running on https://localhost:3000 makes a GET request to the `/fblogin` route it gets blocked due to **CORS error saying (Missing Allow Origin Header)** but when I inspect the request the request URL is absolutely correct.

Only thing I think I need to do is somehow I need to add the header of Acces-Control-Allow-Origin in its response headers.

But I tried using `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://localhost:3000")` in the request but it didn't work..

I'm providing the code for your reference. (please correct me where I'm going wrong.)

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
var cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const FacebookStrategy = require("passport-facebook").Strategy;
//Initializing passport
router.use(passport.initialize());
//Initializing passport Session
router.use(passport.session());
const options = {
  origin: "https://localhost:3000",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
router.use(cors(options));
passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.APPID,
      clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/login/fblogin/callback",
      profileFields: ["id", "name"],
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
      console.log(profile);
      return cb(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  cb(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, cb) {
  cb(null, obj);
});

//END POINTS
router.get(
  "/fblogin",
  passport.authenticate("facebook", { scope: "public_profile" })
);
router.get(
  "/fblogin/callback",
  passport.authenticate("facebook", {
    successRedirect: "callback/profile",
    failureRedirect: "callback/failed",
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:3000");
  }
);
router.get("/fblogin/callback/profile", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ messege: "You are a valid user" });
});
router.get("/fblogin/callback/failed", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ messege: "You are not a valid user" });
});
exports = module.exports = router;
```

> I'm using Express with node.js

Comment: I’m guessing `passport.authenticate` probably redirects to the Facebook login dialog here? Then you can not make any background requests for it, the FB login URL is not CORS-enabled (for obvious reasons - it needs to be called directly in the browser, so that users can verify via the address bar, that they are not entering their credentials into a phishing page.)

Comment: @CBroe I think you are correct, can you tell me what modifications I need to make to make things work

Comment: I'm new to  backend technologies, it will be really helpful if you correct my code. I'm making a GET request from frontend to the URL `https://locahost:5000/login/fblogin` when Facebook login button is pressed to do Facebook login.On localhost:5000 my backend server is running